# View Not being rendered on installation of T4MVC

Tags: c#, .net, t4mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application. I recently installed T4MVC templates by using the package manager:

```
Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

PM> install-package T4MVC
```

This caused T4MVC.tt and T4MVC.tt.Settings.t4 to be included in my project and a bunch of files to be autogenrated (I have about 10 controllers in the project). Right after that I tried to build and run my project, and though I get no errors, on one of the controllers, none of the actions are being rendered. Meaning the browser is being served up a completely blank page instead of the one generated from the associated view. All other controllers work fine.

I really cannot discern what the differences are between this one controller and others that are working fine, and like I said there are no errors... just a blank page is served up when I hit an action on that controller.

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: I figured it out. This controller had an action called "View". That confused T4MVC. Lesson learned. Don't call an action "View" if you want to use it with T4MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, I understand what would happen: for each action, T4MVC also generates an overload without any params, so in this case it would be a method called View with no params, which then hides MVC method with the same name/signature. Note that you probably got a warning, e.g.

```
'Mvc3Application.Controllers.HomeController.View()' hides inherited member 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View()'.
Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
```

We could put some logic in T4MVC to cover that special case, but I'd say if you can just avoid that action name, that'll be better :)

Comment: Yup I did get that warning. It will be great if T4MVC can handle that but in the end I think it is probably a better idea not have an action named View. Thanks for your answer.